# How can I define same response output field name in NestJS using the @Expose decorator from class-transformer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

Currently, I have my Entity defined as so:

```js
export class ItemEntity implements Item {

  @PrimaryColumn()
  @IsIn(['product', 'productVariant', 'category'])
  @IsNotEmpty()
  itemType: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  @IsUUID()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  itemId: string;

  @OneToOne(() => ProductEntity, product => product.id, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  @Expose({ name: 'bundleItem' })
  producttItem: ProductEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ProductVariantEntity, variant => variant.id, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  @Expose({ name: 'bundleItem' })
  variantItem: ProductVariantEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => CategoryEntity, category => category.id, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  @Expose({ name: 'bundleItem' })
  categoryItem: CategoryEntity;
}
```

I added in the `@Expose()` decorator because I want to be able to return one of `productItem`, `variantItem`, or `categoryItem` as just a single `bundleItem` field in the response. Any single one of them can have a value, but NOT two or three of them.

But when I do a GET on the ItemEntity's controller, my desired effect is only applied on the first item, not the others:

```js
[
    {
        "itemType": "category",
        "itemId": ""
        "bundleItem": {
            "categoryType": "Custom",
            "description": "First custom category",
            "id": "e00ad76c-95d3-4215-84b1-de17c7f1f82c",
            "name": "Category A",
            "updatedAt": "2023-02-24T08:49:22.913Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "itemType": "variant",
        "itemId": "",
        "bundletem": null
    }
]
```

I want the effect to extend to the other items in the returned array response. But currently, they are `null`. Essentially, I want the response to return a `bundleItem` field, regardless of what type the `itemType` is, be it `productItem`, `variantItem`, or `categoryItem`. Can I achieve that using `class-transformer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the `@Transform` for this. The `@Transform` decorator contains a few arguments that you can use in the transform process, one of them is the object itself.

```js
@Transform(({ value, key, obj, type }) => value)
```

The following example contains an object with two properties, if one of them is `null` or `undefined` we return the other

```js
import {Exclude, Expose, Transform} from "class-transformer";

export class ExampleDto {
  constructor(partial: Partial<ExampleDto>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose({ name: "new_property" })
  @Transform(({ value, key, obj, type }) => {
    return obj.property1 ?? obj.property2;
  })
  property1: string | null;

  @Exclude()
  property2: string | null;
}
```

Controller

```js
  @Get("example")
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  getExample(): ExampleDto {
    return new ExampleDto({
      name: "Name",
      property2: "value 2"
    });
  }
```

The result is

```json
{
    "name": "Name",
    "new_property": "value 2"
}
```

Although this might work, I **highly** recommend you to not use the same class for your database entity and the DTOs. This can cause all sorts of issues; right now your `ItemEntity` is representing two different concepts at the same time, a entity in the database and also a contract with the external world. Any changes in your model would also reflect in the API (and also the other way around).

Comment: This worked, thank you. 

I initially wanted to make a polymorphic type for my `bundleItem`, but I wasn't able to with TypeORM. Any advice as to how I could achieve that without going through all this transforming stuff?